# Why isnt my javascript working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

All my code seems to work except my javascript am I doing something wrong?
Thanks Im only a beginner!

I am trying to make the background change when the mouse goes over the 'Tags' tab but it wont do it? What is going on?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// This changes color on mouseover, leaves existing color box.
$('.tab-item').mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass("tab-mouseover");  
}).mouseout(function() {
$(this).removeClass("tab-mouseover");
});


// This changes color when clicked, removed old color box. 
$('.tab-item').click(function() {
$('.tab-item').removeClass("tab-selected");
$(this).addClass("tab-selected");
});-->
</script>
<link href="arg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


<div class="tab-item tab-selected" id="search-box">
Search
</div>
<div class="tab-item" id="tag-box">
Tags
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-item {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
font: 14px helvetica;
color: #000;
height: 20px;
float: left;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
position: relative;
width: 75px;
}

.tab-mouseover {
background: #bdbdbd;
}

.tab-selected {
background: #c0c0c0; 
}
```

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using jQuery but haven't included it.
You also need to put your jquery code into the jquery ready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This changes color on mouseover, leaves existing color box.

$(function(){
    $('.tab-item').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("tab-mouseover");  
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("tab-mouseover");
    });


// This changes color when clicked, removed old color box. 
    $('.tab-item').click(function() {
        $('.tab-item').removeClass("tab-selected");
        $(this).addClass("tab-selected");
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Jeez, of course that's what it is... here I am testing out his code in an environment that already had it :)

Comment: Ah i am very confused by all this is there a simpler way to do what I want by just getting the mouseover background effect?

Comment: For the mouseover only, you can use CSS: .tab-item:hover { background: #bdbdbd; } will change the background colour when the mouse is hovering over the element. For the colour change on click you're going to need some JavaScript action, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't added your library (jQuery, I think) as a source here.
Add it like this:

```
<script src='http://foo.com/bar/library.js'></script>
```

If you are, indeed using jQuery, you can directly add the following code to make it work:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
```

Note that the above means you are depending on the availability of the jQuery website and not your own.

As per James' comment on this, yes, you can scrap the jQuery completely, but I'd recommend you to learn JavaScript yourself instead of copying code from a website. If you want to change the background color of the field onmouseover, use code like this:

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#bdbdbd';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white';">Search</div>
```

Or

```
<div onmouseover='this.className="tab-mouseover"' onmouseout='this.className=""'>Search</div>
```

Or without JavaScript and just simple CSS:

```
<style>
.tab-mouseover:hover{
background: #bdbdbd;
}
</style>
<div class='tab-mouseover'>Search</div>
```

I can't answer the latter part, because I don't understand the use of deleting and then adding the same class to an element onclick.

Comment: It would be wise to close that script element.

Comment: Yeah, I had written that, but for some reason it didn't get through. Formatting error? Was editing it.

Comment: Is there a way to scrap the Jquery and just use onmouseover="" feature? I am so confused is there a simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: @James, yes, there is, and I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you haven't included a link to the jQuery library in your code. As a result, your code won't work, wherever you put it.

Second, since your code is in a `script` element at the `head` of the document, it will execute before the `body` of the document has been rendered. You need to put it in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
     * Your code here
     */
});
```

block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.tab-item').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('tab-mouseover');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('tab-mouseover');
    }
);

$('.tab-item').click(function() {
    $('.tab-selected').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $(this).addClass('tab-selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dDTv/1/